# date_hierarchy = 'publication_date' ERROR

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently on [chapter 6 of the Djangobook tutorial](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html). I am follow instructions and everything works perfectly UNTIL!!!

I add date_hierarchy = 'publication_date' to my code

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'publisher', 'publication_date',)
    list_filter = ('publication_date',)
    search_fields = ('title',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publication_date'
```

The above is what I have on my admin.py model so far.

The error I am getting is

```
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/books/book/
    Django Version: 1.4.3
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'
    Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py in date_hierarchy, line 302
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/bradford/Development/Djangocode/mysite',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
    Server time:    Sun, 3 Feb 2013 03:42:02 -0600
```

Not quite sure what to do! Any help is appreciated!

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Do you have a models.DateTimeField named 'publication_date' on your 'Book' model?

Comment: Could it have been overwritten with Book.publication_date = 'somestring' (i.e. classname.publication_date)?

Comment: i dont think so because I've only used publication_date once in all my models and that is located in Book @möter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `publication_date` in your `Book` model hasn't been set which is why you see the `no attribute 'year'` error (a blank string has no year attribute as it's not a real `datetime`).

Try changing the `publication_date` field to

```
publication_date = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

and empty your database to start again (old models will still be blank and produce this error). The `auto_add_now` will prepopulate the `publication_date` to the time that the model was created and you can change it later. More information on `DateField` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

Note that you only see this error when you add the sorting option as up until now you haven't had cause to access the `publication_date` field - and so no errors have been raised.

#### Edit

You can completely reset your data base with

```
$ python manage.py sqlclear <app_name> | python manage.py dbshell
```

which prints out the SQL for clearing the DB `sqlclear` and then that gets sent to the DB (`|` or pipe) to `dbshell`. Then run

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

to re-sync your models and DB. Note, you won't normally need to go through all of this!

Comment: also when I add 'auto_add_now' i get an unexpected keyword argument error but this occurs w/o emptying the database

Comment: I was wondering. Each time i add a new column or edit a column in my database, will i have to go through this process? delete and sync?

Comment: Hopefully not! The reset was so that new `Book` models have the `publication_date` set. Simple model additions usually only need `syncdb`, if you're making significant *changes* and want to preserve data, check out data migrations with [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html).

Comment: awesome! thanks for the resource!! ill read up on it on my free time! thanks for the help again! much appreciated!